# Custom handling of OnBackPressed MvvmCross - don't close app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'd like to add custom handling of method OnBackPressed in Xamarin Android with MvvmCross framework. I've tried something like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "Table", NoHistory = true)]
public class Table: MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {           
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.View_Table);                 
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        //base.OnBackPressed();
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.View_MainMenu);
    }
}
```

and the app went to MainMenuView but one single button (which directs to TableView) inside this view was disabled. 
I've been trying with something like:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.View_MainMenu);
}
```

in MainMenuView but it doesn't work. Should I add some piece of code into ViewModels instead of in Views? Or bind somehow events in a layout? If it is possible to handle that kind of behavior, how to achieve that?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you using the physical back buttons or the ones in the navigation bar? It is really difficult to help you when the intended behaviour and problem is not clearly defined.

Comment: I'm using the physical back button. The scenario is simple. I have MainMenuView with one button, which directs to TableView. In TableView I want to implement such behavior that after pressing the physical back button app won't be closed, but will go to MainMenuView or previously displayed View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using MvvmCross features if you write your code like this.

Just remove "History = true", remove your OnBackPressed() and OnResume() handlers and MvvmCross will handle your back to MainMenu as expected.

When using MvvmCross, you need to use your ViewModels and not your Views to navigate (at least, in a classic scenario).

Comment: @BartoszJasiewicz Fine! Can you just put this answer as "accepted"? Thank you!